# Way to keep lighting from lamps without influence from environmental textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, light

I did a nice little motion track:

[Motion Tracked](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Rj7h_MP4waTWJRNkd5RDBPN2M/view?usp=sharing)

I want to apply a glossy material with a little bit of roughness to give it a metallic look, and in the reflection of the metal, I want to see the surrounding environment.  I plan on using a still image from the original footage and applying it as an environmental texture (in Cycles).  Is there any way to make it so the environmental texture only influences the reflection, and has  no influence on the lighting?  If so, please explain to me how this can be accomplished.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want reflections from an object or world texture, deactivate everything but glossy in object's or world's ray visibility :
[image]

Comment: He is using it for motion tracking, if he is using a mixture of Diffuse and Glossy he should absolutely use the Diffuse setting, transmission and volume scatter are less necessary. Using the world settings might work for him, but for more complex projects I'd recommend not messing with them. World settings should not be fiddled with if it can be helped, it is better to keep things localized.

Comment: i agree, but this is the simple and easy version, good for testing, understanding and basic setup. The world is an exemple. I didn't think it was necessary to add a screenshot with an object as the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, however you can add a sphere, add the texture to it using a *Diffuse* material, and then disable the *Shadows* option.

Add a *UV Sphere* to your scene (*<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*), and scale as desired (*<kbd>S</kbd>*).

Now go into edit mode (*<kbd>Tab</kbd>*) and select all (*<kbd>A</kbd>*) and unwrap using sphere projection (*<kbd>U</kbd> > Sphere Projection*)

[image: Sphere Projection]

Now set up your material like this:

[image: Material Setup]

Now all you need to do is to disable the casting of shadows. Go to *Object > Ray Visibility* and disable the *Shadow* option **and the *Camera* option**.

[image: Shadows]

If the reflections are not quite apparent enough you can try setting the material of the sphere to an *Emission* shader instead of *Diffuse* and tweaking the value.

Here are my results:

**Diffuse**

[image: Diffuse Example]

**Glossy**

[image: Glossy Example]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  I enjoy the convenience that having a Blender Stack Exchange website brings, and thank you for your input.

Comment: No problem, glad to help